# Is there a way to pull all the images from a local directory using python on flask framework & display the images on a html image gallery webpage?

Tags: python-3.x, image, flask, directory

Actually i have a image gallery web page and there are two steps that i wanna perform i.e
(1) - I want to upload images from the web page to a local directory on my computer
(2) - I want to display all the images that i have on the directory to another webpage that i have made as a image gallery

I have accomplished the first part of my problem successfully but the second part is bothering me and i am not able to achieve it and i have used many different techniques but none of them is working.

so, can someone please advice something,
the upload function and the display function that i used is below

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, 
send_from_directory,render_template
from werkzeug import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'E:/os/uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
        filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
           return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file', filename=filename))
   return '''
   <!doctype html>
   <title>Upload new File</title>
   <h1>Upload new File</h1>
   <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
   <p><input type=file name=file>
      <input type=submit value=Upload>
   </form>
  '''
  @app.route('/show')
  def uploaded_file(filename):
     return render_template('template.html', filename=filename)

  @app.route('/uploads')
  def send_file(filename):
     return send_from_directory(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename)

  if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run()
```

the problem is it is only displaying the image that i am upload at that instance, but i want to pull multiple images and save them in some sort of data structure like a list and then iterate through it on the html page and display the images one by one

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Flask - Jinja Templating](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/). You can easily send multiple files to an HTML template and you can use `for` loop easily in the template only to iterate your list of image files and render multiple images on the same page.

Jinja templating - for loop example here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-using-for-loop-in-flask/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible approach:

**python's side**

```
import glob
# OTHERS IMPORTS

@app.route('/show')
def uploaded_file():
    # this function returns as a list all the files that are in the directory 
    gallery_images = glob.glob('/path/to/your/directory/*')
    print(gallery_images)
    """
        the print will return for example: ['a.png', 'lion.jpg', 'python_logo.jpeg']
    """
    return render_template('template.html', filename=galery_images)
```

**HTML's side**

```
...
<div class="row">
    {% for f in filename %}
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="{{url_for('static',filename='images/gallery/')}}{{ f }}" width="100px" height="100px">
            </div>
        </div>            
    {% endfor %}
</div>
...
```

Notice how I specified the path to the directory and how I mixed it with the names of the files obtained during the iteration

Comment: @SauravSikdar Glad to have helped. Do not forget to validate the answer and upvote for it...